# Detect Ctrl + A in keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect the <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> event in input. I can find the <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> event, but the function is continuing even after `return false`.

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/f6rcgpmh/4/

```js
$('.searchTerm').keyup(function(e) {

    $("#status").text("");

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97) { // 'A' or 'a'
            console.log("Control pressed");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#status").text("This should not work if Ctrl + A is pressed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search" class="search">
    <input class="searchTerm" placeholder="Filter Books...">
    <input class="searchButton" type="submit">
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

I want this to work in `keyup` not in `keydown`. Because I am using autosearch and I don't want to call function before keyrelease. And also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> won't highlight text in keydown when it returned false.

Comment: What does <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> do in your browser?

Comment: it prints the text ...its not breaking from function

Comment: `keydown` triggers before `keyup` right?

Comment: It's because when you release the last key, either there is no more `ctrlKey`, either the keyCode is not `a` or `A` anymore

Comment: @TheWarlock : yupe..check http://jsfiddle.net/f6rcgpmh/7/ .not working for single letter.

Comment: Can you check all the answers ?

Comment: @ebilgin : yupe checking

Comment: Is it working for you ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually the function stops. What you are experiencing is that two keyup events trigger: the one from <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and the one from <kbd>A</kbd>.

The first one returns as expected because it does fill the requirements: `ctrlKey == true` and `keyCode == 65 || keyCode == 97`.

But the second one, there will be only one key pressed so both statements can't be true together:

- If you last released the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, then `ctrlKey` is true but `keyCode == 65 || keyCode == 97` is not.
- If you last released the <kbd>A</kbd>, then `ctrlKey` is now false.

Then the line which sets `#status` to an error message is run.

Answer (score 10):

Actually it's not. You must change your event from `'keyup'` to `'keydown'`. Then try it again. You can check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/f6rcgpmh/5/

---

If you need control on autocomplete, you have to put your controls before sending the data.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keyup event trigger causes your problem. I added another condition to your code,

```
if (e.keyCode == 17) // Ctrl key, fires at Ctrl's keyup.
    return false;
```

You can check my new fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/f6rcgpmh/10/.

Comment: I know it works in keydown..I need it for keyup..Reason is I am using autosearch in textbox and I want to search only after keyup.

Comment: If you prepare fiddle like what you have, i can help more.

Comment: This actually *does* work with keyup... at least now in 2022, which is great because e.ctrlKey does not work in keyup as of yet on chrome.