# Redirect function on keycode

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a keycode to redirect users to new page in javascript, but my code is not working.
Does anyone have a solution?

```
if (keyCode == 17&&65) {
        window.location = "somerandompage.html";
    }
```

Comment: @Samathingamajig Nope, that expression is equivalent to `(keyCode == 17) && 65`, also `17 && 65` evaluates to 65 not 17.

Comment: It seems like OP wants it so that pressing `Ctrl+a` to redirect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Ctrl + A in keyup event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912784/detect-ctrl-a-in-keyup-event)

Comment: OP, is this all you have? Or is this inside a window keydown listener?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how detect CTRL+q in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510126/how-detect-ctrlq-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want it so that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> will redirect, which can be done by checking that <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed, and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is already pressed

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 65 && event.ctrlKey) {
    alert("Ctrl+a pressed");
    window.location = "somerandompage.html";
  }
});
```

Comment: @Samathingamajig Please check for duplicates before answering (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510126/how-detect-ctrlq-in-javascript)